# Python Class Inheritance, __init__ and cls

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, class-method, class-variables

The desired output of the code is that I have a class variable Team.stuff which has one entry holding the b instance, and the Player.stuff variable should be empty.  Instead I get an error...

```
class Player:
  stuff=[]
  def __init__(self):
    cls.stuff.append(self)

class Team(Player):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Team, self).__init__()

b=Team()
```

ERROR

```
cls.stuff.append(self)
NameError: global name 'cls' is not defined
```

I could pass the cls variable in the `Team.__init__()`, but I'm not sure if that is the "correct" way, and more importantly the `Player.__init__()` would need a class variable, and I'm not sure on the syntax on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Player(object):
    stuff=[]
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff.append(self)

class Team(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Team, self).__init__()

b = Team()
print(Team.stuff)
```

prints (something like)

```
[<__main__.Team object at 0xb7519dec>]
```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't what I need.  I need print(Team.stuff), NOT print(b.stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `cls` is not a keyword in Python.  Rather it is a convention for the first argument of a method when that method is supposed to be a class function and not one that is called on a particular instance of something.

If you want `stuff` to be an **attribute** of a function, you have to define it like so: `self.stuff=[]`.

And then, when you refer to it in methods, do it with the `self` keyword as well: `self.stuff.append(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `cls` in your `__init__` function is not defined. The argument names `self` and `cls` are just **naming conventions**. In reality, you could name them `foo` and `bar` for an instance and a class method respectively, and `foo` would point at the class instance whilst `bar` would point a the class itself.

Moreover, `self.stuff` would be valid as when searching for an attribute, if an object does not have an attribute of such name in it's `__dict__` dictionary, the `__dict__` of it's class is looked instead. If both are missing, further lookups are done according to `mro` order.

Notice that, once you *set* an attribute `stuff` on an object instance, it will *shadow* the class definition.

Explained by example:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    stuff = []

class MyClassB(MyClassA):
     def __init__(foobar):
         # `foobar` points at the instance of `MyClassB` class.

         # MyClassA.stuff gets `1` object appended to it.
         foobar.stuff.append(1)

         # This should print '[1]'
         print foobar.stuff

         # `MyClassB` object gets a _new_ attribute named `stuff` pointing at a list.
         foobar.stuff = []

         # This should print '[]'.
         print foobar.stuff
```